# auto return true to javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I don't understand why it doesn't work,on js it usually work.

I mean what's wrong in it ?? when a box open it should return true directly

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Moderate Faster
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  A tool to moderate faster for moderators, it bypass alert box
// @author       Kai Smith
// @match      *://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.confirm = function myConfirm() {
  return true;
}

const a = confirm("Are you sure")
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Seem to work in the snippet I made

Comment: it doesn't with tampermonkey

Comment: It also works in Tampermonkey. As long as you use the correct `@match` (Stack Overflow snippets run on `https://stacksnippets.net/`) and you make sure that the confirm runs _after_ your user script runs (using `@run-at document-start`).

Comment: I will check using run at document start :)

Comment: well it still doesn't work

Comment: When I click on a button in another script connected to a function with a confirm, it still shows the confirm box

Comment: @BlackSouleZOD We can't really help you if we can't reproduce the problem. If I use [this user script](https://jsfiddle.net/ya7x2vem/) and run `console.log(confirm('test'));` [it logs "true"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YobE7.png) without showing the confirm box.

Comment: on the console log of the specified web they say "[Violation] 'click' handler took 2255ms" is there any relation ?

Comment: I don't think so. That message is just a warning that the click function took over 2 seconds. `confirm()` is a blocking function which means that as long as the box is open, no other JavaScript can be executed. For `confirm()` that is not much of a nightmare because they need to click one of the buttons anyway and don't need to do anything else, but other functions that take that long generally completely freeze the page which is not something users like.